# PhpStorm method not found

Tags: phpstorm

I love PhpStorm code inspection. But I got one problem with it. When I chain multiple methods inspection stop working and warn me the method is not found.

I develop with Symfony and got a lot of forms. In each form the fourth `add()` is not found.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
      ->add('subject')
      ->add('originator')
      ->add('issueDatetime')
      ->add('amount'); //This one gets an warning
}
```

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-50041 (similar code to yours) ... which is marked as duplicate of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-49688